# What is Silent mode in Ring Fit Adventure?

Tags: ring-fit-adventure

I have been playing Nintendo’s Ring Fit and I noticed this “Silent mode”. I am wondering what this is. Please tell me and explain everything to Silent mode. I am using it but I don't know what it does.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this](https://www.cgmagonline.com/reviews/ring-fit-adventure-switch-review/amp/) article, Silent/Quite mode removes the need jog in place in order to move your character. Instead, you can move your character by squatting.

This feature is designed to give the user the ability still play without potentially disturbing the household or neighbors (e.g. an apartment complex)